# Getting commandText value cannot be null or empty using QueryValue with Webmatrix

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

**I am getting an error when querying the value of an entry on another page, just after it is inserted into the database. The error is as follows:**

```
Value cannot be null or an empty string.
Parameter name: commandText
```

**The Stack Trace looks like this (not sure if this helps):**

```
[ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or an empty string.
Parameter name: commandText]
   WebMatrix.Data.Database.QueryValue(String commandText, Object[] args) +20791
   ASP._Page_EntryViewer_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\administrator.OKMCITY\Documents\My Web Sites\Persons Of Interest\EntryViewer.cshtml:101
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors) +69
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +151
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +62
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext) +114
```

**The line the error occurs on (line 101):**

```
Line 99:     var db = Database.Open("PersonsOfInterest");
Line 100:
Line 101:    var activeID = db.QueryValue((string)Session["activeEntrySelectQueryString"], (string)Session["gPOIName"], (string)Session["gDateLastModified"], (string)Session["gGender"], (string)Session["gRace"], (string)Session["gHeight"], (string)Session["gWeight"], (string)Session["gHairColor"], (string)Session["gEyeColor"], (string)Session["gDOB"], (string)Session["gAge"], (string)Session["gSS"], (string)Session["gDL"], (string)Session["gDOC"], (string)Session["gVehicleTag"], (string)Session["gFBI"], (string)Session["gOfficer"], (string)Session["gAdditionalDescriptors"], (string)Session["gHomePhone"], (string)Session["gAliases"], (string)Session["gSourceOfInformation"], (string)Session["gAddress"], (string)Session["gAddressInformation"], (string)Session["gKnownAssociates"], (string)Session["gVehicleDescription"], (string)Session["gCellPhone"], (string)Session["gCellPhone2"], (string)Session["gCellPhone3"], (string)Session["gPOICautions"], (string)Session["gComments"], (string)Session["gWorkPhone"], (string)Session["gSummarizedIncidents"], (string)Session["gPOILastName"]);
Line 102:    Session["gEntryID"] = activeID;
Line 103:
```

I can't seem to find a reason for this error, as it occurs just after a user "saves" his/her entry into the database but occurrs sporatically and seemingly randomly. The page attempts to query the value of the unique primary key for that entry. The values stored within the session variables you see above were stored from the values previously just used to insert the new entry into the database (I have to do it this way because the primary key "is identity" and the value is automatically incremented with each entry addition).

There may be a better (simpler) way to do what I am trying to do, but I thought doing it this way would be more consistent than simply using MAX (aggregate function) on just the primary key.

There is probably more information I could give on this issue, but I really don't want to fill this page up with unnecessary information (if I haven't already). Just let me know if there is anything else I can provide.

**A few more notes:**

The 'Session["gDateLastModified"]' is grabbed from a field on the form that is automatically plotted using JavaScript, so this value (accurate down to the second) should (like all of the other variables in this query) match the values just entered into the database (Yes, I am sure that the user has JavaScript on and functioning correctly).

Also, it is probably obvious, but the QueryValue command on line 101 has the first argument as the select query string, using parameterized queries, of course, and the rest of the arguments are what must match to retrieve the row in the database.

Remember this error only occurs occasionally.

I am really sorry if I have added too much information (or left something out), but I don't know where to begin assuming what this problem might be, so not sure what all might help any who are trying to help me.  Just let me know if there is anything else I can provide.

**UPDATE**

All I know for now is that a string is deliberately filled as long as it 'IsPost' then that string is used to directly fill the Session variable in question. I know that session variables are actually cookies, but being pretty certain that no one is manually clearing them (and they'd have to do that after hitting the submit button and before the next page loads, somewhere in the middle of this process), what else could cause this value to become cleared? I assume that commandText is a variable that is passed the value of my query string during db.QueryValue, is this correct?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check that the session actually has the values before using them:

```
var activeEntrySelectQuery = (string) Session["activeEntrySelectQueryString"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(activeEntrySelectQuery)) {
    throw new ArgumentException("The active entry select query has gone missing.");
}
```

You could add appropriate additional information (and create your own type of exception) to help you find the issue. But I suspect this is the problem - the session doesn't contain the value you expect.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me. I will try that, and thank you! But don't think I forgot about you, as this error may not come up again for a little while. If this is the problem, I promise I will accept (of course it is good advice, nonetheless). Thanks again!

Comment: @VoidKing I hope you get to the bottom of it - hopefully you can at least get more data to see if there is a pattern about when this goes missing - for example the session is cleared by an app_pool recycle and you get a flurry of them at the same time.

Comment: All I know for now is that a string is deliberately filled as long as it 'IsPost' then that string is used to directly fill the Session variable in question. I know that session variables are actually cookies, but being pretty certain that no one is manually clearing them (and they'd have to do that after hitting the submit button and before the next page loads, somewhere in the middle of this process), what else could cause this value to become cleared? (I assume that commandText is a variable that is passed the value of my query string during db.QueryValue).

Comment: Yes - your db.QueryValue probably creates a SqlCommand with CommandText of "SELECT * FROM SomeWhere". It may be worth seeing if there is another way of passing the query and parameters other than session to see if it is more stable.

Comment: That's really a good idea, I think I'll just do that with a hidden input field and see if this problem just goes away (if I can, the way the pages are setup, that is).

Comment: I'm not sure how I could use hidden input field because when the user submits the form, it posts back to itself, the strings are plotted, among many other things, then it redirects to the EntryViewer (not Post) where the error occurs And, judging by the options given here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/192/Transferring-Data-Between-ASP.NET-Web-Pages -- I don't think I have a more stable option but a query string, but one of the fields passed is a Social Security #, so I don't know if I want to do that. In the future we ARE planning to use SSL, so I guess it should be OK, right?

Comment: Ignore my comment about SSL, I think I was confused for a second on how query strings were displayed in the browser.

Comment: I have one more question: Does it make any sense at all to use Cache? I have no problem doing this, but I would like to make sure that it is stable enough for this, first. It seems to be my only viable options, considering that I don't think there is a way to use C# to manually post to another page (or I would just use a hidden input field).

Comment: Personally, I would design it so you don't need to pass this information along. i.e. if you want to accept a piece of data from the user, collect that, then pass it to a method that performs the query. Don't pass the query around.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but as I am still really noobish, I'm not sure how this could help me. I can pass the data to a .cs file, but how can I retrieve this "remembered" value on a different page? The method alone will remember it until I switch pages and retrieve it with the other? Am I missing something? How could I design it like your scenario above? Thanks, and sorry for so many questions.